# Sets Data Structure in Golang

Tags: programming-languages, data-structures, go

I really like google golang but could some one explain what the rationale is for the implementors having left out a basic data structure such as sets from the standard library?

Comment: The language is actually called Go, not golang

Comment: But "golang" is more searchable

Comment: Way more searchable. Googling "go set" returns images of a wooden board with black and white pieces.

Comment: I believe the community advice is to use Golang, not Go, for the above reasons - searchability

Answer (score 74, accepted):

One potential reason for this omission is that it's really easy to model sets with a map.

To be honest I think it's a bit of an oversight too, however looking at Perl, the story's exactly the same. In Perl you get lists and hashtables, in Go you get arrays, slices, and maps. In Perl you'd generally use a hashtable for any and all problems relating to a set, the same is applicable to Go.

**Example**

to imitate a set ints in Go, we define a map:

```
set := make(map[int]bool)
```

To add something is as easy as:

```
i := valueToAdd()
set[i] = true
```

Deleting something is just

```
delete(set, i)
```

And the potential awkwardness of this construct is easily abstracted away:

```
type IntSet struct {
    set map[int]bool
}

func (set *IntSet) Add(i int) bool {
    _, found := set.set[i]
    set.set[i] = true
    return !found   //False if it existed already
}
```

And delete and get can be defined similarly, I have the complete implementation [here](http://play.golang.org/p/_FvECoFvhq) . The major disatvantage here is the fact that go doesn't have generics. However it is possible to do this with `interface{}` in which case you'd have cast the results of get.

Comment: I've seen comments by Go authors suggestion that generics are a hoped-for feature, there being a hurdle in the way of needing to work out what the best idomatic pattern should be before committing to extending the language.

Comment: Here's my slightly-revised version with Contains and Size methods: http://play.golang.org/p/tDdutH672-

Comment: How does this approach work for user defined set-values? And does it lend itself to an easy implementation of intersections/unions etc.?

Comment: Instead of `map[int]bool` one can use `map[int]struct{}` instead. I prefer the last.

Comment: `map[int]struct{}` .. The `struct{}` takes 0 bytes.

Comment: https://github.com/fatih/set is an implementation of my based on maps and empty structs. It's thread safe and has a simple api.

Comment: With `map[int]struct{}` you can't do `if mymap["key"] {` to check for membership. Google [recommends using `bool`](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) (search for "A set can be implemented").

Comment: @Timmmm, but you can do `if _, ok := mymap["key"]; ok {/*stuff*/}`

Comment: Yeah but that is far more verbose.

Comment: @Timmmm: "A set can be implemented as a map with value type `bool`." is far from being the same as "Google recommends using `bool` [instead of `struct{}` for the value type of a map as a set]." Also note that the key point of the paragraph containing the quoted sentence is the zero return value for nonexistent entries, and that `map[T]bool` is an example where that property can be useful.

Answer (score 3):

I think this has to do with `golang` focus on simplicity. `set`s become really useful with `difference`, `intersection`, `union`, `issubset`, and so on.. methods. Perhaps `golang` team felt that it is too much for one data structure. But otherwise a "dumb set" that only has `add`, `contains` and `remove` can be easily replicated with `map` as explained by @jozefg.

Comment: i disagree. a set is mostly used for membership checks and uniqeness semantics. a set implementation would be perfectly usable without those methods. that being said, they are also trivial to implement.

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer works ONLY IF the key are a built-in type. To complement the previous answer, here is a way to implement a set whose elements are user-defined types:

```
package math

// types

type IntPoint struct {
    X, Y int
}

// set implementation for small number of items
type IntPointSet struct {
    slice []IntPoint 
}

// functions

func (p1 IntPoint) Equals(p2 IntPoint) bool {
    return (p1.X == p2.X) && (p1.Y == p2.Y)
}

func (set *IntPointSet) Add(p IntPoint) {
    if ! set.Contains(p) {
        set.slice = append(set.slice, p)
    }
}

func (set IntPointSet) Contains(p IntPoint) bool {
  for _, v := range set.slice {
    if v.Equals(p) {
      return true
    }
  }
  return false
}

func (set IntPointSet) NumElements() int {
    return len(set.slice)
}

func NewIntPointSet() IntPointSet {
  return IntPointSet{(make([]IntPoint, 0, 10))}
}
```

Comment: "works ONLY IF the key are a built-in type" is **wrong**. `type mySet map[IntPoint]bool` works perfectly well. All that is required of the key type used in a map is [that it has `==` and `!=`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types). Equality of struct types is well defined, your `Equals` method should be just `p1 == p2`.

Comment: It is true that equality for structs is well-defined, but if the struct contains maps or slices as fields, they will be compared by reference, rather than by value. This may not be what you want.

Comment: I take a bit of issue with this solution, because `Contains` takes linear time, while `aMap[]` takes constant time, regardless the number of members. A better solution would internally create a unique key based the contents of each member, and leverage the constant-time querying that the `map` type provides. Even faster solutions that consider cache behavior, etc. exist as well.